# how i can execute windows command line in background?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface

how i can execute windows command line in background

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're after start!

```
start /B <yourcommandhere>
```

> /B
>     Start application without creating a new window. The application has ^C handling ignored. Unless the application enables ^C processing, ^Break is the only way to interrupt the application.